# Access the $refs of a parent from a child - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hopefully this has been answered before - essentially I'm trying to append a block ("CodeBlock.vue") to an element inside App.vue from an onClick event triggered inside a sibling of CodeBlock, and a child of App.vue, ("ButtonSidebar.vue"). I'm a little confused by emitting events and/or using an eventBus Vue instance, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated:

So far I have the following. CodeBlock.vue which will be used as an instance and appended to a div inside App.vue.

CodeBlock.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :class="type">
    THIS IS A CODE BLOCK!!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CodeBlock',
  props: [ 'type' ]
}
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <ButtonSidebar/>
    <div id="pageBlocks" ref="container"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

// import { eventBus } from './main'

import AddTitle from './components/modules/AddTitle'
import AddSubTitle from './components/modules/AddSubTitle'
import ButtonSidebar from './components/modules/ButtonSidebar'
import CodeBlock from './components/modules/CodeBlock'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    AddTitle,
    AddSubTitle,
    ButtonSidebar,
    CodeBlock
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.no-border {
  border: unset !important;
  border: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

ButtonSidebar.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button class="btn-circle absolute-float-tight text-dark" v-on:click="reveal=!reveal">
      <font-awesome-icon v-if="!reveal" :icon="faPlusIcon" />
      <font-awesome-icon v-if="reveal" :icon="faMinusIcon" />
    </b-button>
    <transition name="custom-classes-transition" enter-active-class="animated bounceInDown" leave-active-class="animated bounceOutRight">
      <div v-if="reveal" class="absolute-float-reveal">
        <b-button class="btn-circle text-dark" v-on:click="addCodeBlock"><font-awesome-icon :icon="faCodeIcon" /></b-button>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import faPlus from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faPlus'
import faMinus from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faMinus'
import faCode from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faCode'

import CodeBlock from './CodeBlock'

export default {
  name: 'ButtonSidebar',
  computed: {
    faPlusIcon () {
      return faPlus
    },
    faMinusIcon () {
      return faMinus
    },
    faCodeIcon () {
      return faCode
    }
  },
  components: {
    FontAwesomeIcon,
    CodeBlock
  },
  data () {
    return {
      reveal: false
    }
  },
  props: ['codeBlocks'],
  methods: {
    addCodeBlock () {
      var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(CodeBlock)
      var instance = new ComponentClass({
        propsData: { type: 'primary' }
      })
      instance.$mount()

      this.$el.querySelector('#pageBlocks').appendChild(instance.$el)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

  .absolute-float-tight {
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .absolute-float-reveal {
    left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .btn-circle {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 34px;
  }

</style>
```

It's around the `this.$el.querySelector('#pageBlocks').appendChild(instance.$el)` part that I start to loose the plot a bit...I'm worried that I have to strip everything down and start again perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you could move the `addCodeBlock` method to the parent component `App.vue` and in the `ButtonSidebar.vue` you could use `this.$emit` to trigger the method in the parent component.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid reaching to the DOM as much as possible. The source of truth for the data should be in your components.
refs are very useful to integrate other js library that needs a DOM element.

So in your case, assuming `codeBlocks` are available in your `App.vue` components, the `SidebarButton` needs to emit an event when it's clicked so that the parent `App.vue` can add a new `Codeblock`:

(I have removed some code not needed for the example. CodeBlock.vue stays the same)

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <ButtonSidebar @add-block="addCodeBlock" />
    <CodeBlock v-for="block in codeBlocks" :type="block.type" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ButtonSidebar from '../ButtonSidebar'
import CodeBlock from '../CodeBlock'

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {ButtonSidebar, CodeBlock},

  data() {
      return {
          codeBlocks: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
      addCodeBlock() {
          const newBlock = {type: 'whatever'}
          this.codeBlocks.push(newBlock)
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ButtonSideBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button class="btn-circle text-dark" v-on:click="addCodeBlock</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>  
export default {
  name: 'ButtonSidebar',

  data () {
    return {
      reveal: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addCodeBlock () {
      this.$emit('add-block')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

A good pattern to follow in Vue is to lift the state to the parents and passing it down as props whenever you feel like you want to share state between parents and children.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve it in this simple way:

App.vue (template section)

```
<ButtonSidebar @add="addCodeItem"/>
<div id="pageBlocks">
    <codeBlock v-for="code in arrCodes" :type="code.type"/>
</div>
```

App.vue (script)

```
export default {
  data() {
     return {
        arrCodes: []
     }
  },
  methods: {
     addCodeItem(codeType) {
        this.arrCodes.push( { type: codeType } )
     }
  }
}
```

ButtonSidebar.vue (script section)

```
addCodeBlock () {
  this.$emit('add', 'yourtype');
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabio - this feels like I can only add one code block not multiple instances of the CodeBlock component...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts so, instead of v-if, you can set a v-for and use an array. When "add" is triggered you can push an item in your array

Comment: @MichaelRoberts I edit my answer using v-for. I didn't test it, but it should work

Comment: Hi Fabio, implemented your suggestions with a few minor tweaks but this has worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: Hi Fabio, just a query tho - say if I wanted to add multiple block types to the CodeBlock element...?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Then you would emit the type you want to add in the event.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts in the way Bert wrote :)

Comment: So I have included that in emit but changed `<div v-for="pageBlock in pageBlocks" v-bind:key="pageBlock.id" :type="pageBlock.type"></div>` such that it is no longer a CodeBlock ...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts you have to change your addCodeItem method to receive the parameter... check this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Comment: @Fabio Hi Fabio - yes, I think I have - `addCodeBlock () { this.$emit('addPageBlock', { type: 'code' }) }`

Comment: Hi Fabio - it's not just CodeBlocks I'd like to append - could be CopyBlocks instances or QuoteBlocks instances ... etc etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173011/discussion-between-fabio-and-michael-roberts).